# How to Split a Cell Part of a Row and Keep the Rest of the Rows - Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to do the following:  I have row 1.  I have values A1, B1, and C1.  A1 contains a few names separated by a comma.  I want to split A1 by these names while copying over the values from B1 and C1 into the split columns of A1.

For example, I have this:

```
(A1              B1      C1)
bob,sam,bill     99      10
```

I want to have this:

```
bob              99      10
sam              99      10
bill             99      10
```

I am also doing this on Google Sheets, I tried using combinations of Split, Join, and Transpose but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
EDIT: any updates?
EDIT: still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(split(A$1,","), 1,ROW()-1))
```

[See it in action here](https://docs.google.com/a/iilab.org/spreadsheets/d/15YrC7ZdY819TU3AZaJx1FyURHPxkPJH4S0KWiU02g2c/edit#gid=0)